# Add a link to the SKU of the product in the order details in the backend

Tags: magento2, product, url, backend

In the backend, click on sales -> orders -> view once, and under the information tab, there is a "Items Ordered" option. Add a product link to the SKU of the product below, which links to the frontend product. As shown in the following figure:

[image]
If anyone could provide some guidance, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create file app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Tarun_StackOverflow" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Create file app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/registration.php**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Tarun_StackOverflow', __DIR__);
```

**Create file app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="left">
            <referenceBlock name="column_name" template="Tarun_StackOverflow::items/column/name.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Create file app/code/Tarun/StackOverflow/view/adminhtml/templates/items/column/name.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Items\Column\Name
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer
 */
?>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogHelper */
$catalogHelper = $block->getData('catalogHelper');
?>
<?php if ($_item = $block->getItem()): ?>
    <div id="order_item_<?= (int) $_item->getId() ?>_title"
         class="product-title">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="product-sku-block">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU'))?>:</span>
        <a target="_blank" href="<?= $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl(); ?>"> <?= /* @noEscape */ implode('<br />', $catalogHelper->splitSku($block->escapeHtml($block->getSku()))) ?></a>
    </div>

    <?php if ($block->getOrderOptions()): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getOrderOptions() as $_option): ?>
                <dt><?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?>:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (isset($_option['custom_view']) && $_option['custom_view']): ?>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getCustomizedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php $_option = $block->getFormattedOption($_option['value']); ?>
                        <?php $dots = 'dots' . uniqid(); ?>
                        <?php $id = 'id' . uniqid(); ?>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['value'], ['a', 'br']) ?>
                        <?php if (isset($_option['remainder']) && $_option['remainder']): ?>
                            <span id="<?= /* @noEscape */ $dots; ?>"> ...</span>
                            <span id="<?= /* @noEscape */ $id; ?>">
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml($_option['remainder'], ['a']) ?>
                            </span>
                            <?php $scriptString = <<<script
                                require(['prototype'], function() {

script;
                            $scriptString .= "$('" . /* @noEscape */ $id . "').hide();" . PHP_EOL;
                            $scriptString .= "$('" . /* @noEscape */ $id .
                                "').up().observe('mouseover', function(){ $('" . /* @noEscape */ $id . "').show();});" .
                                PHP_EOL;
                            $scriptString .= "$('" . /* @noEscape */ $id .
                                "').up().observe('mouseover', function(){ $('" . /* @noEscape */ $dots .
                                "').hide();});" . PHP_EOL;
                            $scriptString .= "$('" . /* @noEscape */ $id .
                                "').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){ $('" . /* @noEscape */ $id .
                                "').hide();});" . PHP_EOL;
                            $scriptString .= "$('" . /* @noEscape */ $id .
                                "').up().observe('mouseout',  function(){ $('" . /* @noEscape */ $dots .
                                "').show();});" . PHP_EOL . "});" . PHP_EOL;
                            ?>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getDescription()) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Result**
[image]

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**